# Several @user in the comment

Tags: feature-request, comment, notifications, comment-replies

When there is a discussion in comments (especially on meta), sometimes I miss an opportunity to call two users in one comment. Hence, when I need to answer both users and I want to be sure that they will receive answers in their inbox, I have to write two comments - which would be meaningless if only both users can be called in one comment. On the other hand, maybe I don't consider some negative situations which may be caused by such feature?

Comment: That [has been declined on Meta.SO two years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment), and I don't think the opinion on that has changed a bit.

Comment: @Fabian: thanks for the link. Although no clear reasons for the declination were stated there

Comment: "No means no!!"

Comment: @Asaf: seems like a quote :) anyway, as one has a right not to implement the feature he does not seem to fit *SE/SO, the other has a right to ask for clear reasons for such decision. Especially bearing in mind that *SE/SO are community-driven sites and community was 'pro' this feature.

Comment: It looks like a quote, but it smells like toxic waste!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tagging more than one person in a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/tagging-more-than-one-person-in-a-comment)

Comment: If needed, you can add a separate comment explaining just something like: @Ilya ping for you too - I think the above comment is interesting for you. (And don't forget that the poster is always pinged when you comment - it's not necessary to ping him.)

Comment: @Martin: thanks for the idea - after pinging another user, I can immediately delete the comment since the notification will still appear in his inbox and hence he will take a look on the thread even if the comment which pinged the user is deleted.

Comment: @Martin & Ilya: one of you should post that work-around as an answer!

Comment: @Willie: with this post I'll check how does the Martin's idea works :) Martin, please put your idea as an answer. I'll ping you now

Comment: @Willie: I posted that bellow as you suggested (and made CW, if someone wants to add something). Although I was not sure whether I should post an answer here - it seems that this question might be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Martin: it might, then again, it might not :) It is good to have the information somewhere visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to put a separate comment just for the sake of adding a ping to a specific user; e.g.

> @XYZ: Perhaps you could check the above comment, too.

Of course, if you prefer, you can delete the comment once you know the person you wanted to ping has been already notified.

---

Aside note: In the comments above it was suggested, that a ping from a comment gets to inbox even if the comment itself is deleted. Based on a little testing, it seems that this does not work. In a related thread at meta.SO: [Is it OK to use temporary comments to notify users interested in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118944/is-it-ok-to-use-temporary-comments-to-notify-users-interested-in-a-post) it is mentioned that:

> I was wrong in my statement in point #1; Inbox notifications of comments that have been deleted do, in fact, get deleted from the Inbox, also... just not immediately. Additionally, deleting the comment immediately after posting it causes there to be no inbox notification in the first place.

In an answer in that thread another possible workaround was mentioned - to ping the user in chat. (However, this can be used only if the user you want to ping uses chat.)

Comment: It would be nice if SE implemented "ephemeral" comments so e.g. "@@Foo please see this meta thread" would be deleted automatically once Foo receives the notification. This would help avoid much noise caused by such localized comments.

Comment: Martin, that doesn't work? I know I quite often have comments in my inbox that are gone by the time I try to review them.

Comment: @cardinal: See the meta.SO thread I've added to the answer.

Comment: @cardinal: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3215/room-for-martin-sleziak-and-ilya) you can find some experiments we've done with notifications for deleted comments.